# How to stop sshuttle from forwarding localhost?

Tags: mac, dns, ssh-tunnel, macos-sierra, sshuttle

When I use `sshuttle` I prefer not to forward `localhost` as some of my services are serving to it. So I checked the man page and it declared the use of `-x` option to exclude any IP. My final command is

```
sshuttle --dns -r SSH_SERVER -x 127.0.0.1 0/0
```

but it doesn't do the trick.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix it? I'm on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug found just recently and should be fixed soon. I solved my problem by going back to the commit before it's origin. [This bug](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/issues/159) was found approximately two weeks ago and [was partially fixed once](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/pull/162).

```
git clone https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle.git
git checkout ef83a5c
sudo ./setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in version `0.78.3`. Didnt exist after upgrading to `0.78.4` using `sudo pip3 install --upgrade sshuttle`

```
Installing collected packages: sshuttle
  Found existing installation: sshuttle 0.78.3
    Uninstalling sshuttle-0.78.3:
      Successfully uninstalled sshuttle-0.78.3
Successfully installed sshuttle-0.78.4
```

Comment: I still have the problem on 0.78.4 :/